# Disable jqModal popup in validation jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the inline editing and add functionality of jqGrid, and I need to perform validation for data inserted in the inline cell during the save operation of jqGrid. For which I have used:

```
editrules: {custom:true,custom_func:customCheck}
```

In the customCheck:

```
function customCheck(){
    ///DO SOMETHING
    return [false,"some message if invalid"];
}
```

It is working just fine, however I don't want to show an error message on the jqModal popup. Instead I want to do something in customCheck() itself.

```
function customCheck(){
    ///DO SOMETHING
    if(invalid)
        //show a error div
        return false;
}
```

I have got no clue whatsoever on how to disable the popup jqModal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirements you can't implement this without changing jqGrid code. Inline editing get you not enough flexibility to display custom message.

You can modify [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L210-L213) and [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L222-L230) to implement your requirements. You can do the modification in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` file. You can use any minification program which you like to produce `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` if required. I personally use [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) in such situations (for example `ajaxmin.exe jquery.jqGrid.src.js -out jquery.jqGrid.min.js`). [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) and [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) can be used alternatively. See my post [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/minifying-jqgrid-from-github/#p27780) for additional information.